# How does the Catholic Church understand Luke 19:17, "Because you have been faithful in a very small matter, you shall have authority over ten cities."

Tags: catholicism, gospel-of-luke, parables

Luke 19:17 occurs in the Parable of the Ten Minas (which has strong similarities to the Parable of the Talents).

Jesus says

> "His master replied, ‘Well done, good servant! Because you have been
> faithful in a very small matter, you shall have authority over ten
> cities.’"

How does the Catholic Church understand this authority of the good servant - is it something that is happening now (as, for example, there are patron Saints of countries), or is this a reference to (the correlate of) cities in the resurrection, and so the good servants don't have this authority as of now?

Comment: My first instinct is that "authority over ten cities" are still within the world of the parable, to be translated to actual rewards in heaven, which doesn't necessarily be in the form of "authority over ten cities", but I'm also curious whether in the new heaven and earth what would be the correlate.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple "My first instinct is that "authority over ten cities" are still within the world of the parable, to be translated to actual rewards in heaven" Ya, that's how I used to view this. But granting authority is a theme in the parable. The disciples are given real authority now, and then rewarded with authority later. So I wonder if this is a reference not just to a generic reward, but real, continued authority.

Comment: Make sense. Would be interesting to find out.